# Difference between unnormalized and normalized probability.

Tags: probability, logarithms

I have an equation : e^y, which is called unnormalized probability. 
And another equation : e^y/sum(e^y), which is called normalized probability. I am not getting the difference between the terms they have used. Like what they mean.

Another thing is that, how log(equation) and just equation varies. Like what inference does log(equation) gives?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability of all events should sum up to 1 --- this is essentially what normalized means (in probability theory). In the example that you have given, if we sum over all possible events $y$ we can't in general say that it is one, in other words, $\sum e^y \neq 1$ in general.

To make this a bit more clear let $y_1,y_2, \dots, y_n$ be all the possible events that $y$ can take, and let the "probability" of each of these values be $e^{y_1}, e^{y_2}, \dots, e^{y_n}$. I've put "probability" in quotation because we know in general $\sum_{i=1}^{n} e^{y_i}$ is not 1. As a simple example to show this if we take $n=2$ and let $y_1=1,y_2=2$ then we know, $$\sum_{i}e^{y_i}=e^1+e^2 \neq 1.$$ 
So we say that $e^y$ is not normalized because it doesn't sum up to 1. However, we can use a simple trick to "normalize" it.  The usual trick in normalizing quantities (and this applies to a lot of other things than just probabilities) is to divide by the sum of all possible values. Going back to my simple $n=2$ example if for each event $y_i, i=1,2$ I assign the probabilities $e^{y_i}/\sum_i e^{y_i}$ then they become normalized. Trivially the sum of the probabilities are
$$ \frac{e^{y_1}}{\sum_{i}e^{y_i}} + \frac{e^{y_2}}{\sum_{i}e^{y_i}} = \frac{e^{y_1}+e^{y_2}}{\sum_{i}e^{y_i}} = 1.$$ 
Notice that the probabilities are the same as I had before the only difference is that I've divided each of them by the total. Since they sum to 1, we say that $e^{y}/\sum e^{y}$ is normalized. The notation you've used isn't very easy to understand --- it's better to say $$ \frac{e^{y_j}}{\sum_{i} e^{y_i}},$$ to highlight that $y$ takes different values.

Comment: Thank you @D.Toe, got clear picture of the formula.

Comment: i have updated the question. Help with with that.

Comment: What is equation? Using the log laws give us that $log(e^{y}) = y$ and $$ log(e^{y}/\sum_i e^{y_i}) = y-log(\sum e^{y_i}).$$ Log is usually taken for computational reasons, but in terms of inference it depends on the context I  suppose. For this example it just gives back the value of the original $y$...